# How to return a parameter with a different type?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

**What I have:**
1. a textblock in the XAML
2. a query from a database which contains a DateTime? type data.

**What I do:**
1. I declare a class "myClass" with a DateTime? parameter named "myDate" 

**What I want**
1. show the MyDate in the textblock [I know]
2. when the value of "myDate" is null, show a string in the textblock. [I don't know, because the Get method can only return a DateTime? type value but not a String type.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Binding with your textblock like this :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myDate, TargetNullValue='Your null message'"/>
```

Comment: Works like a charm and easy like a piece. Does this trick work for all the Binding which source type can be null?

Comment: @AlbertGao I think it works with all nullable types, but never really needed it before so you have to start experimenting. :D

Comment: Thanks @BigL and everyone who paid time in this post:)

Comment: @BigL You should also look at The [FallbackValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.95).aspx) binding.  It is a little more flexible than the TargetNullValue that you've specified above, in that it is triggered on null-result bindings as well as bindings that fail in some other way.

Comment: @ChesterHusk i know the FAllbackValue too, but i didn't know it is triggered if the binding is OK but the value is null. :) And for the above specified problem the TargetNullValue is a simple and easy solution, a straight forward too.

Comment: @BigL I hadn't ever heard of the TargetNullValue binding before, which will come in handy, I'm sure.  I'm assuming that you can set more than just strings to it? Anything of the required type of the Binding? Like in this case you used a String, because the parent property was a String, but for Background you could set a TargetNullValue of a particular Color?

Comment: @ChesterHusk i googeld it now and yes you can set to different types, depends on the properties type you are binding too, for example i found this for a calendar control "TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:DateTime.Today" in this case you use have to add the mlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib". It should work with colors too.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a string variable; if `myDate` is not null, assign it the date's value - otherwise set it to whatever the default is. Examples:

```
string stringToShow = null;
if(myDate.HasValue)
{
  stringToShow = myDate.Value.ToString();
}
else
{
  stringToShow = "other string";
}
```

or, more concisely with a ternary

```
string stringToShow = myDate.HasValue ? myDate.Value.ToString() : "other string";
```

Then show `stringToShow` in the textblock instead of `myDate`. Finally, you could wrap this in an extension method to make it super easy to call:

```
public static string ToSpecialString(this DateTime? date)
{
  return myDate.HasValue ? myDate.Value.ToString() : "other string";
}
```

Then you can just call `myDate.ToSpecialString()` in the front end.

Comment: why is that bad engineering practice?

Comment: I generally frown on ternary operators; if you ever have another case to handle, or need to do something more complex than simply assigning a variable, you now have to rip out an old piece of code and replace it with an if/else block. Basically, it makes for more work in maintaining your codebase. Plus, they make things harder to debug.

Comment: I would regard the conditional operator as *entirely* valid in this case. Sure, if you need to do anything more complicated it would be worth pulling it out into separate if/else clauses, but for this specific case - assign one value or another, based on a condition - the conditional operator is ideal. I'd refactor the first form into the second if I saw it in a code base I was maintaining.

Comment: Fair enough - just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a converter which will do 'is null' check and return information string when it is.

This will allow you do it directly from XAML, using standard Data Binding, without any additional code in code-behind file.